# Adding ternary operator in echo statement

Tags: php

I'm using this echo statement in a php script and it works fine

```
  echo "<li class=\"ui-state-default\" id=ID_$this->id>$this->course_name <i class=\"fa fa-bars\" style=\"font-size:0.7em;color:#cccccc;float: right;\"></i> </li>";
```

now i'd like to add this ternary statement into the li tag

```
 (($benchmark>$thisUser)? style="color:red":"")
```

in essence to turn the color red under the IF conditions...right now this doesn't produce any but code....does anybody know how this should appropriately go into the echo statement?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you cut your code in chunks in order to make it more readable (taking advantage of the fact that HTML treats multiple spaces and/or line-breaks like a unique whitespace).

Also, as altready suggested by others, for this peculiar case you had better separating your ternary operation, yet for readability.

```
$color = $benchmark->$thisUser ? '#cccccc' : 'red';
echo "
<li class='ui-state-default' id='ID_$this->id'>
    $this->course_name
    <i class='fa fa-bars' style='font-size:0.7em; float: right; color:$color;'></i>
</li>
";
```

It would work as well if you include the ternary operation inside the echo, but looks not so readable

```
echo "
<li class='ui-state-default' id='ID_$this->id'>
    $this->course_name
    <i class='fa fa-bars' style='font-size:0.7em; float: right; color:" . ($benchmark->$thisUser ? '#cccccc' : 'red') . ";'></i>
</li>
";
```

Note that in this case you have to wrap the ternary operation between parenthesis, or the concatenation will break.

Comment: Glad to help. So could you consider accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a valid PHP statement:

```
style="color:red"
```

You probably meant to make the whole thing a string:

```
($benchmark>$thisUser) ? 'style="color:red"' : ''
```

Comment: right...thanks...that was my error when I wrote it down.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put a ternary into that echo statement. Just use a variable...

```
$liStyle = ($benchmark>$thisUser) ? 'style="color:red"' : '';
echo "<li class=\"ui-state-default\" $liStyle id=ID_$this->id>$this->course_name <i class=\"fa fa-bars\" style=\"font-size:0.7em;color:#cccccc;float: right;\"></i> </li>";
```